# Mouse rightclick on Openlayer 3

Tags: mouseevent, coordinates, openlayers-3, ol3-google-maps

Is is possible to get the mouse right click event on Openlayer3? If so how can i get the latitude and longitude of the right clicked location.

i have got the right click event by following

```
map.getViewport().addEventListener('contextmenu', function (evt) {

});
```

How can i get the latitude and longitude of the right clicked point?

Comment: refer this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148428/how-can-i-select-a-feature-in-openlayers-3-by-right-click-it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `map.getEventCoordinate` method to get your coords. Also use the evt.preventDefault() to get rid of the native right click menu.

```
map.getViewport().addEventListener('contextmenu', function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
console.log(map.getEventCoordinate(evt));

})
```